# MySQL to JSON for Facebook Application

Tags: mysql, json, facebook, mongodb, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to build a Facebook app similar to the way Nike+ does to record runs. My lab's application tracks walking, jogging, sitting, standing, etc. and stores it into a MySQL database with appropriately designed tables for storing this information (userid / date / run_sec / walk_sec / etc).

What I've been trying to do is take that data from MySQL and store it into JSON files each day for each user, maybe into an external database running MongoDB. This might not be the best approach, however, I think that learning experience would be beneficial.

I've run into many brick walls, and I'd like to know if anyone has ever created such a project in the past? I've searched github to try to get an idea, but not much is out there. Ideally I'd like to be able to login to the MySQL database, grab my activity data each day (I'll work on multiple user ids at a later time) and store it into MongoDB and build the Facebook application from there.

Any help, suggestions, ideas, etc are welcomed and highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'll add my 2c for whatever its worth; Would you not be better off having the client (Facebook application) query a server which then pulls the information from the database as a single json request, and returns that request to the client for the client to decode and work with? I'd expect the user to be able to get upto-date information at any stage, not just once a day. You could cache the return to once every n minutes or so if bandwidth/performance is of concern.

Comment: I hope that I'm understanding correctly. The user would connect the Facebook application to their activity profile on our website. From there they would basically "SEND" the current data from the current date's table? For one instance, say 9AM, their WALK_SEC data would be 300, but 5 hours later, they would "SEND" again and change that 300 value to 500, or whatever else the highest value matches?

Comment: This actually is too broad. If you are looking for a discussion try [programers.stackexchange.com](http://programers.stackexchange.com) instead, or otherwise try to ask something more specific here that is suited to the Q&A format of a direct question